# Help with Punctuation

Tags: comma-splices

How should this sentence be punctuated?

> With experience, handling difficult clients; demanding deadline, tight budgets and changing expectations, Corrine was perfect for the job.

Comment: I am perplexed that anyone would ask a question about punctuation, and begin it with an obvious punctuation error of not starting with a capital letter.

Comment: Shouldn't it be *deadlines*? Otherwise, *demanding deadline* needs an article.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, it should be-

"With experience handling difficult clients, demanding deadline, tight budgets and changing expectations, Corrine was perfect for the job."

Hope you were trying to convey the same meaning that this statement now gives.

Answer (score 0):

Well, more natural:

***Experienced in handling*** difficult clients, demanding deadline**s**, tight budgets, **and** changing expectations, Corrine was perfect for the job.

or:

***Experienced, able to handle*** difficult clients, demanding deadline**s**, tight budgets, **and** changing expectations, Corrine was perfect for the job.

An Oxford comma is required before the "and" before the last element of a serial list. 
The "with" makes the sentence heavier.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Oxford comma is considered unacceptable in most British style manuals: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma#Mainly_British_style_guides_opposing_mandatory_use

Comment: Chicago Manual of Style is fully behind it, though. Isn't that ironical, to have Americans support an item with a British name, only to have it rejected by Brits? :-)